# how to send data from model to screen?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, ionic2, angular2-routing

I want to add Todo using model .When I click `Add todo` button (bottom one)..It open the model .I need whatever I type in input field it shoud add in list ..

so how to send inputfield  data to screen or page .I want share data between model and screen/page ..How to add item in list using model ?

here is my code

http://plnkr.co/edit/N6aXDZXUr99MC6w77H6d?p=preview

```
import { Page ,ViewController} from 'ionic-angular/index';

@Page({
  template: `
  <ion-content padding>
    <h2>Add Todo!</h2>
    <input type='text' placeholder='Enter todo'>
     <button (click)="add()">ADD</button>
    <button (click)="close()">Close</button>
  </ion-content>`
})
export class MyModal {
  constructor(viewCtrl: ViewController) {
    this.viewCtrl = viewCtrl;
  }

  close() {
    this.viewCtrl.dismiss();
  }
  add(v){
   alert(v.value);
   v.value='';
    this.viewCtrl.dismiss();
  }
}
```

how to set data on list ..? how to update todo array ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you are trying to solve is really how to pass data back from a modal to the page that presented it, which has a straightforward solution using modal's functionality.

These small changes to your plunker work as you intend, with no need to hook events.

On your `home.ts` :

```
showModel(){
      let modal = Modal.create(MyModal);
        modal.onDismiss(data => {
        this.addItem(data);

      })
    this.nav.present(modal)
    }
```

on your `mymodel.ts` :

```
  add(v){
    alert(v.value);
    this.viewCtrl.dismiss(v);
  }
```

When you dismiss the modal, it passes back the value `v` to your home page. Your home page captures the data in the onDismiss callback, and adds it to the `todo` array.

**edit:** the working plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/iKIfFYYoJolPkDgx2pxT?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about ionic but yes you can do tha same using `Eventemitter` by doint so you call one function
on click of add item of modal and one event is fired from your modal.ts with value of textfield.
than eaisly you can add the value of text field into your list :-

here is simple Workarea using `Eventemitter` may help you.

my app.ts :-

```
<div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 text-center">
    <a *ngFor='#Number of numberList'>
        {{Number}} &nbsp; &nbsp; Click Button To Delete &nbsp; 
        <delete (deleteFun)="DeleteElement(Number)" [pk]='Number'></delete><br>
    </a>
</div>
```

from here i am firing event named `deleteFun` and from delete modal i am catching the event like this :-

```
DeleteFunction() {
  this.deleteFun.emit('emit');
}
```

<kbd>[Working Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/AiDiNl8SrSKIwDUYWl50)</kbd>

For more info you can refer here

> https://github.com/MrPardeep/Angular2-DatePicker

Comment: hmm sure if you need any help comment here.